# Why can't I call upon the same Google map on separate pages? Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, maps

Real new to this side of programming, but trying to get my feet wet.

I created a map and I have no problem getting it to show up and function correctly, but when I try and put the same map on a different page, it won't show the map. It creates a space for the map, but I can't see it.

I can get the map to load on the second page ONLY IF: I place it ahead of the original map page in my code.

How can I get the map to show on both pages?

RELEVANT SCRIPT:

```
  var map;
  function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.628936,-122.672273),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);


var myMarkers = [
    ['angst', 45.629281,-122.671468, 4],
    ['northbank', 45.62911,-122.671468, 3],
    ['gallery360', 45.628144,-122.67245, 5],
    ['auroa', 45.629118,-122.671763, 5],    

  ];



  for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
      var newMarker = myMarkers[i];
      var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker[1], newMarker[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: newMarker[0],
          zIndex: newMarker[3]
      });

   }




 } //close initialize function



 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

PAGE THAT WORKS BECAUSE IT APPEARS FIRST IN CODE:

```
<div data-role="page" id="map" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="content" id="content" data-theme="a">   
    <div id="map_canvas"> </div>    
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" id="footer">    
    <div id="nav" data-role="navbar" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#galleries">Galleries</a></li>
            <li><a href="#shows">Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of footer-->

</div> <!-- end of #map page -->
```

THE PAGE I CAN'T GET TO LOAD, UNLESS IT'S CODED AHEAD OF THE PREVIOUS.

```
<div data-role="header" id="header" >
    <a href="index.html" data-role="home" data-icon="home"  id="homebutton" >Home</a>  <!--home button on header bar-->
    <h1>Gallery 360</h1>
</div> <!--end of the header div-->

<div data-role="content" id="gallerylist" data-theme="c">   

    <img src="images/360.jpg" class="pagebackground" />
    <div id="map_canvas"> </div>    
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" id="footer">    
    <div id="nav" data-role="navbar" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#galleries" >Galleries</a></li>
            <li><a href="#shows" >Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of footer-->
</div><!-- /page #g360 -->
```

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery Mobile. Are you trying to get the map to load after you drill into a new page? You would have to reinstantiate the map instance when you drill into the new page.

Comment: I'm sorry, super beginner here. Reinstantiate the map instance? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experinenced too, but can be because you didn't put the "data-role='page' id='' " in the second page